# Scroll to Top Not working in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

Navigating back to top of the page is not working after user scroll down to bottom of the page.

Page footer

```
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="b">
    <div class="ui-bar">
        <a href="" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-u" data-theme="d" style="float:right;" class="returnTopAction">Return top</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery Reference

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE:**
My full HTML code

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>SQ/TR</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="arealistpage">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                 <h1>SQ/TR</h1>

                <a href="../Default.aspx" class='ui-btn-left ui-btn-back' data-icon='arrow-l'>Back</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-filter="true" data-inset="true" data-role="listview">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Design Squad Check</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Vendor Squad Check</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Business Squad Check</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Management Squad Check</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Design Transmittal</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Vendor Transmittal</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Business Transmittal</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Management Transmittal</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" id="footerNavBar">
                <div class="ui-bar">
                    <a href="" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-u" data-theme="d" style="float:right;" class="returnTopAction">Return top</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [jQuery.mobile.silentScroll()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.silentScroll/) method in jQuery Mobile which scrolls to a particular Y position without triggering scroll event listeners. This method does not perform animated scrolling.

Example using jQuery Mobile silentScroll:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>SQ/TR</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on('click', '.returnTopAction', function() {
                $.mobile.silentScroll(0);
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="arealistpage">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                 <h1>SQ/TR</h1>

                <a href="../Default.aspx" class='ui-btn-left ui-btn-back' data-icon='arrow-l'>Back</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-filter="true" data-inset="true" data-role="listview">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Design Squad Check</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Vendor Squad Check</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Business Squad Check</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Management Squad Check</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Design Transmittal</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Vendor Transmittal</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Business Transmittal</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Management Transmittal</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" id="footerNavBar">
                <div class="ui-bar">
                    <a href="" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-u" data-theme="d" style="float:right;" class="returnTopAction">Return top</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
    </body>

</html>
```

Moreover you could use the following script which performs **animated** scrolling:

```
$(document).on('click', '.returnTopAction', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#arealistpage").offset().top}, 1000);
});
```

You may check the below example which is based on your code:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>SQ/TR</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on('click', '.returnTopAction', function() {
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#arealistpage").offset().top}, 1000);
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="arealistpage">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                 <h1>SQ/TR</h1>

                <a href="../Default.aspx" class='ui-btn-left ui-btn-back' data-icon='arrow-l'>Back</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-filter="true" data-inset="true" data-role="listview">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Design Squad Check</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Vendor Squad Check</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Business Squad Check</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Management Squad Check</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Design Transmittal</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Vendor Transmittal</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Business Transmittal</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Management Transmittal</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" id="footerNavBar">
                <div class="ui-bar">
                    <a href="" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-u" data-theme="d" style="float:right;" class="returnTopAction">Return top</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind an on click event to the button and use jquery anmiate to scroll to top for sliding effect.

HTML

```
<a data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-u" data-theme="d" style="float:right;" class="returnTopAction">Return top</a>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', ".returnTopAction", function()
    {   
       $("body").animate({"scrollTop": 0});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: hi! thanks for the answer. Jquery mobile has the sliding effect when scrolling. is there any way i can have the sliding effect here?

Comment: Update the answer above, check it.

Comment: Just to mention that the $(document).ready() function should not be used in jQuery Mobile. The reason is that Ajax is used to load the contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready handler only executes for the first page.